# SVN error : svn: E175009: Missing update-report close tag

Tags: svn

Today I tried to update SVN and I got this error:

> svn: E175009: Missing update-report close tag

I checked the svn repo:

```
svnadmin verify <path>
```

It showed me:

> ..
>   * Verified revision 150.
>   * Verified revision 151.

I think the repo is OK.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What version of SVN client and server are you using?

Comment: SVN Client : 1.8.8
SVN Server : 1.6.11